# Flash on website works with Flash viewer 10 but not 11

Tags: flash

On my DotNetNuke website, I have a flash player that shows rotates through a few images.
`http://www.capitoltrack.com/desktopmodules/Flash%20Image%20Rotator/DataSprings_FlashRotator.swf?cachekill=825&version=3.0&filename=/Portals/19/DataSprings_FlashImageRotator_988_3e2fcc72_b472_4b56_96d7_c432de5c138f.xml`

All of a sudden, it no longer shows images in either IE, Chrome or Firefox. I downloaded the stand-alone flash player for both version 10 and 11.

The above link works in 10, but does not work in 11. Any idea why?... and how I can fix for version 11?

Answer (score 0):

Was fixed by Flash update to 11.5.